How the metal-adsorbate coupling matrix element 'V' is obtained?
In DFT based studies on metals for catalysis, the adsorption energy of the adsorbates is explained with the coupling matrix element V between molecular orbitals and metal d-states. Is it obtainable from DFT packages like VASP and QE or is is an explanation?
Few references
https://doi.org/10.1016/0039-6028(96)80007-0
https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.chemmater.6b04229
